# Which service should I use to run scheduled task on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a `apache beam` program on python. To save running cost I would like to executed this python using service instead of on EC2 instance.

The script lasts from `50s` to over `60min`.

If this is GCP I think `google app engine`. However, on AWS, I am not sure whether I should use `AWS beanstalk` or `AWS batch` .
Generally, which service is best to run long running script on AWS?

Thanks,
Yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Batch is recommended for batch processing at any scale, However AWS Elastic Beanstalk is an easy-to-use service for deploying and scaling web applications.

Also there is no additional charge for both the services AWS batch & AWS Elastic Beanstalk. You pay for AWS resources (e.g. EC2 instances or AWS Lambda functions) you create to store and run your application.

In your case Apache Beam is used which is an unified model and set of language-specific SDKs for defining and executing data processing workflows/pipelines which fall under category of **batch processing**.

References:

https://aws.amazon.com/batch/?nc=sn&loc=0

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, in my case I simply  wanted to execute the script without any additional environment configuration thus I chose to use **AWS Instance schduler**. Ideally , I understood that  AWS batch is the right choice.